# ruby on rails how to give an ID and a redirect handler to rails button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have declared a rails button_tag as follows

```
<%= button_tag "Save"   %>
```

I dont know a way to give it an ID or a define a handler . Can anyone tell me a way to do it . I referred http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag but could not find much .

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: do you want to give an `id` as `params` or do you want to save a `form`?

Comment: id as a param . I could not find any internet resource where they  have defined the ID or the handler

Comment: If you want to redirect to a url with `id` as param, you should probably use `button_to`, I am not quite getting whether you want this button to submit a `form` or redirect to a `url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<%= button_tag "Save", :id => 'button_id'   %>
```